# How to add a custom class to my UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my current app I have 24 different views, each view has it's own `ViewController`. As the time has passed I have come to the realization that changing them to a `TableViewController` would not only function better, it would also in fact look better.

Typically the way that I have been assigning the custom classes to my views has been to go in Xcode to: File > New > File > Objective-C Class.

I make the class and make sure that it is a subclass of `UIViewController`. After the file has been created I click on my View Controller in the Storyboard file, go to the inspector and set the custom class to be `myNewViewController`, all done!

But this is not the case when working with a `UITableView`, I was able to add a table view in the storyboard file, customize it / add the sections / cells, etc, but when I would like to assign a new class that I have created following the steps mentioned above, except this time I subclass from `UITableViewController`

I get the following warning: 
[image]

With this being the incomplete code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 0;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Additionally, the view shows up blank in when ran on my iOS device.

I am aware that this implementation must be completed before it can properly run, but is there a specific way of this that it would link the view that I was working with and it's ViewController? This way none of this configuration is needed?

What is my next step to follow?

Thanks for the & advice!

**Edit** I have also attempted to set the cell identifier to "Cell", and also tried changing the values so that numberOfSections returns 5, and numberOfRowsInSection returns 2 but still no luck, app crashed and I get this in the debug log:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
***
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using static cells. You shouldn't use the data source methods.

Comment: I have edited the code in the question, the method you mentioned is already being implemented. @Abdullah Shafique

Comment: Yes but in this method you are supposed to determine what the cells contain.

Comment: Did you set the cell identifier in your storyboard?

Comment: Yes I have set the cell identifier to "Cell", and also tried changing the values so that numberOfSections returns 5, and numberOfRowsInSection returns 2 but still no luck @Abdullah Shafique

Comment: In tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath after UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier   forIndexPath:indexPath]; insert this code:

Comment: @vzm cell.textLabel.text = @"Hi";

Comment: I did, but app still crashes. Should i delete the rest of the content that is in the view in the storyboard? @Abdullah Shafique

Comment: Try taking out "for index path" in UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get it to work, even after deleting the forIndexPath :[  I have no idea what the problem could be at this point, any other ideas / suggestions? Would you like to see anything in particular in my code? PS, Thanks for taking the time to help me out! @Abdullah Shafique

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33599/discussion-between-abdullah-shafique-and-vzm)